# Openssl file decryption error bad decrypt. Wrong key or incompatible version of Openssl?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I've been trying to decrypt a file I encrypted few years back. I don't remember the password, so I've been going through a list of potential passwords I might have used back then. One of these passwords produces an error different from the error I get with any other password.

Is it possible I've found the right password, but something else goes wrong?

This is the command I use:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -in <in.aes-256-cbc> -out <out> -k <password>
```

I have 11 potential passwords for this file. For 10 passwords the command returns error:

```
EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/ ... /evp_enc.c:330:
```

But for one password the error is different:

```
EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/ ... /evp_enc.c:337:
```

What is the difference between these two errors?

I'm using OpenSSL version 098-59.60.1 on OS X

Comment: Also see [Apple OpenSource | OpenSSL](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/OpenSSL/).

Answer (score 2):

These are very likely two different error conditions, both to do with padding:

```
n=ctx->final[b-1];
if (n == 0 || n > (int)b)
    {
    EVPerr(EVP_F_EVP_DECRYPTFINAL_EX,EVP_R_BAD_DECRYPT);
    return(0);
    }
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    if (ctx->final[--b] != n)
        {
        EVPerr(EVP_F_EVP_DECRYPTFINAL_EX,EVP_R_BAD_DECRYPT);
        return(0);
        }
    }
```

PKCS#7 padding, as used by OpenSSL, is always applied. It will pad with one to 16 bytes depending on the size of the plaintext. 1 byte valued `0x01`, two bytes valued `0x02` etc., up to 16 bytes (the block size) valued `0x10` if the plaintext is exactly N times the block size.

So lets take a look at the code, where `b` is the block size (16) and `n` is the value of the last byte. You see that it immediately errors out if `n` is zero (an invalid value, see above) or if it is larger than the block size `b`. Only after validating the last byte will it check if the other `n` bytes in the last part of the block have the same value as the last byte `n`.

So unfortunately you haven't found your password: it's just that the error in the padding after using a wrong password is returned later in the code.

Note that if you try long enough you may create a decrypted last block where the padding is correct *by chance*. Obviously that chance is slightly larger than 1/256 as that is the chance to generate a last byte valued `0x01`, the smallest padding that can be generated. In that case you may have to look at the decrypted message and check if the contents are correct.

Comment: *"So unfortunately you haven't found your password: it's just that the error of the padding is returned earlier in the code...."* - Padding Oracles FTW!

Comment: @jww Yeah, then again, there are padding oracles on CBC even without it. As long as they don't use this function in TLS 1.2 as that would be amazingly bad.